# Wordpress custom metabox checkbox to display text on front page

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, meta-boxes

I'm creating a video site in wordpress that will feauture both videoes and live streaming. The live streaming is occational and I'm trying to add a checkbox in the "new post" section where the user can check the box to display an alert that they are streaming live on the front page.

This is my code so far, but it does not save that the chebox is checked.

```
function register_post_assets(){
    add_meta_box('live-tv', __('Live TV'), 'add_featured_meta_box', 'post', 'advanced', 'high');
}

add_action('admin_init', 'register_post_assets', 1);

function add_featured_meta_box($post){
    $featured = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'live-tv', true);
    echo "<label for='live-tv'>".__('Is this a live broadcast post?', 'foobar')."</label>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='live-tv' id='live-tv' value='1' ".checked(1,         $featured)."     />";
}

function save_featured_meta($post_id){
if (isset($_REQUEST['live-tv']))
    update_post_meta(esc_attr($post_id, '_featured-post', esc_attr($_REQUEST['featured-post']))); 
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_featured_meta');
```

I'm also wondering how i can check if the checkbox is checked to display content on the front page. Thank you so much for your time and any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your save_featured_meta function:

It has to be like this:

```
function save_featured_meta($post_id)
{
    if (isset($_REQUEST['live-tv']))
        update_post_meta(esc_attr($post_id), '_featured-post', esc_attr($_REQUEST['featured-post']));
}
```

You didn't close the esc_attr() at the right place.

Comment: Thank you! Do you (or anyone else for that matter) have any idea how I can use the checkbox to display content on the front page when it is checked. It is supposed to be used when live streaming is available.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please mark it as the answer to your question. As for you comment; Please post this as a new question.